# how to use quran package with pdflatex compiler?

Tags: pdftex, packages

how to use quran package in TexStudio with pdflatex compiler? Please give me more examples, thanks!!!
...

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{quran}
\usepackage{utf8}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\title{{\fontsize{26}{20}\selectfont\bf QURAN} }
\author{Me}
\date{4 Mart, 2024}
\begin{document}
    \setcode{utf8}
    \quranayah[1][2]
    
    %\maketitle
\end{document}
```

And I got the problems:

```
texstudio_KkEXJg.tex: ошибка: 17: Unicode character ا (U+0627) not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where does package utf8 comes from?

Comment: @Mensch I really not good at it, how can I fix the problem? Thank you

Comment: all the examples in the quran package documentation use lualatex or xelatex, not pdflatex, why do you want to use pdflatex?

Comment: ok, I started in xelatex, but how can I use both arabic and english letters in my document, such that both languages should written correctly, english from left to right, and arabic ...?